# Sequential Files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How to read/parse a Sequential File written by previous Map Reduce Job. The keyOut and ValueOut of prev MR Job were Text and ByteWritable. What should be the keyin and valuein for the mapper of my next MR Job. I expect the record to have key and value as Text.

Answer (score 0):

If your previous running M/R Job has the output k/v of Text and ByteWritable, the Input of your following job is going to be Text and ByteWritable.

So your Mapper definition of the follower job should look similar to this:

```
xyz extends Mapper<Text, ByteWritable, KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
```